# Eclipse: in the Libraries tab all buttons are disabled

Tags: eclipse, jar, buildpath

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) and Java 9.0.4. I created a project via right-click *> Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Libraries*. All buttons are disabled like *Add JARs*, *Add External JARs..., etc.:

[image: screen shot of error page]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8):

You first have to **select either *Modulepath* or *Classpath***.

The *Modulepath* is a very new thing for Java 9 (here you can watch a [short video how it can be used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=37s)). It exists since the Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a), October 11, 2017. In case of doubt, I recommend selecting *Classpath*.

Answer (score 2):

When this window is open first click on the 'Modulepath' > After that 'Add JARs' option get enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and this is what worked for me, I got it from another post.

From looking at the shared screenshot. You have selected the Modulepath in the panel.

Un-select that and you will be able to add external jars.
You can click on the Classpath to move the control away.

I hope this works for you.