# All the keys in libraries tab seem to be disabled when I am trying to add an external JAR file for jdbc in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I am using Eclipse IDE version 2019_9 R(4.13.0).

Here's the screenshot of the problem:
[image: Here's the screenshot of the problem.]

What can I do to enable the add external jar box?

I see this question has been asked previously here:
[Eclipse: in the Libraries tab all buttons are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491394/eclipse-in-the-libraries-tab-all-buttons-are-disabled)
but I couldn't find anything to apply to solve the problem.

Comment: Click either on _Modulepath_ or on _Classpath_.

Comment: Thanks. Might sound dumb, but that's what I had done,and it didn't do anything. However after trying now, its activated.Probably,some problem with my mouse.

Comment: Whatever, great that it works now.